# AudioFingerprinting and Normalization

Tags: c#, audio, compression

I've written an application which allows audio fingerprinting using the method described [here](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/). It basically converts an mp3 to a wav and then creates a bunch of hashcodes in a database. I then create a recording using my iphone which has some noise and compare the hashcodes and get matches as documented in the link. Wow, its cool!!

Im now recording radio samples using a USB radio receiver. I get the sound data in a byte[] array and then do exactly the same thing where i store the hashcodes and then try to match it. This time it doesnt work.

My feeling is that the mp3 has been normalized (had compression applied to it) and this might be the difference. I couldnt think of any other differences as they are both (the mp3 and radio sample) converted to wav format (16bit)

I guess my question is twofold:

1. if i compress the radio sample do you think that itll work?
2. To do this i need to apply a compression function which means i need to make the soft sounds louder and the louder sounds softer.

Ive started writing a function which takes a byte array (of the wav data in 16 bit format) and wanted to cycle through it and adjust the sample values accordingly to do the compression but im struggling with this:

```
List<short> ints = new List<short>();
        for (int j = 0; j < byteArray.Count; j+=2)
        {
            //so for 16 bits every 2 bytes in the array is a sample
            short sample16 = 0;
            byte[] sample = new byte[2];
            sample[0] = byteArray[j];
            sample[1] = byteArray[j+1];

            sample16 = (short)(double)BitConverter.ToInt16(sample, 0);
            //at this point change the sample according to the compression needed
            ints.Add(sample16);

            //back again to test it
            byte[] buffer11 = BitConverter.GetBytes(sample16);
        }
```

Comment: OP: I removed the "normalization" tag as this tag refers to database normalization, not data compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **sblom** already stated in his comments, frequency domain hashing is not affected by dynamic range. According to your given information, I would think lacking of some frequencies between your inputs. Note that, MP3 has a psychoacoustic audio model which based on human perception. It precisely discards or masks some frequencies. So, your radio source may include or lack of some important frequencies to correctly recognize your inputs.

Comment: thanks guys, im currently sampling at 44100hz, 16bit and 1 channel. Would lowering the sampling range maybe help?

Comment: It depends on source IMO. If it has mostly high frequencies, then lowering sampling range would eliminating those frequencies (or lowering them). And according to your implementation description, you would lost some important finger prints in the source. I think, ideally both inputs should have same sampling rate.

Comment: i think i need to change my hashing function to be a little more forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of important background in order to get this right. What you're specifically trying to do is called [Dynamic Range Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression).

I think what you'll want to do is measure the average amplitude over a segment of the samples (probably using [Root Mean Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude#Root_mean_square_amplitude)). And then divide all the samples in that segment by that RMS average amplitude. This will result in having the same RMS amplitude over the entire song.

You'll have to experiment with what the right length is for each segment. Probably, if it's 10-40 ms, it'll be short enough that volume changes won't sound too jarring and long enough that you'll get a good RMS measurement.

Comment: Thank you, is your feeling that adding Dynamic Range Compression will make it produce the correct data? or do you think there will be other processing ill need to do on the data?

Comment: That's super hard to say, and depends entirely on your choice of audio hash. My _hunch_ is that the radio introduces other distortions, too. But exactly what distortions and how to make your hash function robust against them is way beyond my experience here. :(

Comment: Okay--actually looking at the article that you linked, the hash is done entirely on frequency domain data. The dynamic range compression algorithm that I described actually shouldn't change anything about the frequency domain data. So I don't think that's what's going on.